# 'STR' object is not callable while execute sql command

Tags: python, sql

I'm try to get 3 data from one function. `X,Y,Z` data from `get_gyro_data()` function. When i'm try to execute these datas in order to insert tab ***TAB_MPU*** and columns **GX,GY,GZ** . I use i2c for gettin data from MPU6050

```
  math functions 
  math functions
  .
  .
  .
  x= x/scaler
  y= y/scaler
  z=z/scaler
  return {'x': x, 'y': y, 'z': z}

def get_all_data(self):
  gyro = get_gyro_data()
```

After get gyro data im tryin to write database like ;

```
while True :
    mpu = MPU6050(0x68) //my sensor
    gyro_data = mpu.get_gyro_data()
    print(gyro_data['x'])
    print(gyro_data['y'])
    print(gyro_data['z'])
    Time = (time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
    Date = (time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
    print (Time + " - " + Date)
    sql = ("""INSERT INTO `TAB_TEMP` (`Date`,`Time`,`JX`,`JY`,`JZ`,`IX`,`IY`,`IZ`) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"""(Date,Time,accel_data['x'],accel_data['y'],accel_data['z'],gyro_data['x'],gyro_data['y'],gyro_data['z'])) 
    cursor.execute(sql)  // execute sql command
```

When i debug program, I got exception TypeError : 'str' object is not callable at `sql= (""" INSERT .... )` line

Comment: This is not  a programming forum. Please ask programming related questions in Stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On that line you're basicly doing this: `""()`

You'll have to separate the SQL query string and the arguments, best in the `cursor.execute()` call. Something like this:

```
sql = """INSERT INTO `TAB_TEMP` (`Date`,`Time`,`JX`,`JY`,`JZ`,`IX`,`IY`,`IZ`) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"""
args = (Date,Time,accel_data['x'],accel_data['y'],accel_data['z'],gyro_data['x'],gyro_data['y'],gyro_data['z'])
cursor.execute(sql, args)
```

Also depending on your database connector you'd need question marks instead of the string formatter.

Comment: Thank you ! Thank you Tank youuu ! :) its work. How can i use question marks. Probably i need question marks because it give error ''not all parameters were used in the SQL statement